# Differential invariants and Lie symmetries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have the following question:

1. Does differential invariants have the same Lie symmetries?
2. I want to know about the relation of differential invariants of an action and their symmetry properties. Does differential invariants of a group action have isomorphic Lie symmetry group?

In [[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363703012_Differential_Invariants_of_the_Fifth-order_KdV_Types_of_Equations)], the authors considered the differential invariants of a fifth-order KdV types of equation (Kawaha KdV equation). Here is the Lie symmetries of the equation:

$$ X_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\qquad X_2=\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\qquad X_3=at\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$$

The third-order prolongation of the operator $X$ has the form

$$X^{(3)}=(c_3 at + c_1)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + c_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}+c_3\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-c_3 au_x\frac{\partial}{\partial u_t}-c_3 a u_{xx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xt}}-2c_3 a u_{xt} \frac{\partial}{\partial u_{tt}}-c_3 a u_{xxx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xxt}}-2c_3 a u_{xxt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xtt}}-3c_3 a u_{xtt} \frac{\partial}{\partial u_{ttt}}$$

In the paper a set of generating differential invariants is found. For instance $u_{xxx}$ is a differential invariant of Kawaha KdV.

Making simple calculations, one obtains

$$X^{(3)}(u_{xxx}) = 0.$$

Therefore $u_{xxx}$ is a differential invariant. However, $u_{xxx}$ has the Lie symmetries:
$$ 
X_1=F_1(t)\partial_x,\qquad X_2=F_2(t)\partial_u,\qquad X_3=F_3(t)\partial_t,\qquad X_4=F_4(t)x^2\partial_u,\qquad X_5=F_5(t)x\partial_x,\qquad X_6=F_6(t)x\partial_u,\qquad X_7=F_7(t)u\partial_u,\qquad X_8=F_8(t)\left(\frac{1}{2}x^2\partial_x+xu\partial_u\right).
$$
The Lie symmetries of $u_{xxx}$ is different from the Kawaha KdV.

In another paper [[2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220535634_Hidden_and_Not_So_Hidden_Symmetries)], the concept of hidden symmetries is raised. According to the paper, a *hidden symmetry* is a Lie point symmetry which appears in the target differential equation after a
change of order using a nonlocal transformation and which does not have a point counterpart
in the source equation.

Comment: The number 1 is a differential invariant of any geometric structure on any manifold and of every system of differential equations in any variables, and also a conservation law of any system of partial differential equations in any variables. It has every diffeomorphism of every manifold as a symmetry. You can see why theories of differential invariants generally give rise to cohomology theories, quotienting out silly things. So the symmetries of a differential invariant can be a larger pseudogroup than the symmetries of the original geometryic structure or pde.

Comment: A PDE has infinitesimal symmetries. In order to "use" one of this symmetries to reduce the PDE I look for differential invariants of this vector field. Trivially, this selected symmetry is a symmetry of the differential invariant. Why is important the relation between other symmetries of the original PDE and other symmetries of the differential invariant? I don't see the point.

Comment: @A. J. Pan-Collantes - Differential invariants have many applications including reduction of PDEs. Here equivalence of PDEs is considered.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. I have only used differential invariants of the symmetry, in order to get a variable change that let me "rectificate" the vector field of the symmetry, and reduce the PDE. But I don't know what is a differential invariant of a PDE